# android layout-land and layout-port issue

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation

I have layout folder with a layout for portrait orientation and layout-land folder with the layout for landscape orientation.
Now such situation: I start app in portrait orientatin - ok, right layout, change orientation - ok, landscape layout, again change orientation - and .. orientation is changed but layout is landscape..
What is it?

EDITED:
code:

```
private TextView mTxtGoDate;
private TextView mTxtGoBackDate;
private TextView mTxtCityFrom;
private TextView mTxtCityWhere;

private TextView mTxtManCount;
private TextView mTxtChildCount;
private TextView mTxtBabyCount;
private TextView mTxtClass;

private CheckBox mCheckOneWay;
private CheckBox mCheckRange;

private RelativeLayout mLayoutGoBack;

private Button mBtnSearch;

private SearchParams mSearchParams;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_search);

    mSearchParams = new SearchParams();

    mTxtGoDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_go_date);
    mTxtGoDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    getDateGo();
    mTxtGoDate.setText(mSearchParams.getGoDate().getDateAsString());

    mTxtGoBackDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_go_back_date);
    mTxtGoBackDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    getDateGoBack();
    mTxtGoBackDate.setText(mSearchParams.getGoBackDate().getDateAsString());

    mTxtCityWhere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_where_city);
    mTxtCityWhere.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTxtCityFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_from_city);
    mTxtCityFrom.setOnClickListener(this);

    mCheckOneWay = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_one_way);
    mCheckOneWay.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    mCheckRange = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check_correct);

    mLayoutGoBack = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_go_back);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.params_layout)).setOnClickListener(this);
    mTxtManCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.param_man);
    mTxtChildCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.param_child);
    mTxtBabyCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.param_baby);
    mTxtClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.param_class);

    mBtnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search_flightes);
    mBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    CitiesDataSource dbCities = new CitiesDataSource(this);
    dbCities.open();
        City from = dbCities.getLatestCity(true);
        City where = dbCities.getLatestCity(false);
        if (from != null) {
            mTxtCityFrom.setText(from.getName());
            mSearchParams.setFrom(from);
        }
        if (where != null) {
            mTxtCityWhere.setText(where.getName());
            mSearchParams.setWhere(where);
        }
    dbCities.close();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(false);
}
```

onResume in superclass:

```
protected void onResume(boolean flag) {
        super.onResume();
    }
```

the other code is unrelated to my question. thanks

Comment: what code? both xml? it is unnecessary

Comment: the Activity code, by default if you created the two folder correct and naming the XML file in both directory with same name there should be no problem

Comment: activity code is very large, it has oncreate, onresume and onactivityresult methods and a lot of my methods

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any special tags in the manifest element for this Activity, such as `configChanges` that might complicate how it selects its resources?

You might also try putting the portrait layout in the default directory, and only have a qualified directory for the landscape layout, i.e.

```
layout/
    //Your portrait (default) layout
layout-land/
    //Your landscape layout overrides
```